# How to redirect to root if param is not found? Angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angular-meteor

I have the following routes, using Angular ui-router.

If I navigate to `/3872` that gives me a user with that ID and the correct template, that's great.

But the problem is, if I type an ID that doesn't exist, such as `/1111` I want to redirect to the `root`. At the moment it stays on the `user` route and gives me an empty template instead.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('root', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'home_controller'
  })
  .state('user', {
    url: '/:userId',
    templateUrl: 'user.html',
    controller: 'user_controller'
  });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

Comment: use `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise({  'redirectTo' :  ' / '  });

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `$stateChangeStart` event to make some filtering. That goes into app.run(...) section

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

        if (toState.name == "user") {
           //some logic... and most probably 

           //event.preventDefault();
           //$state.go(toState.name, toParams);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In user_controller($stateParams,$state):

```
if($stateParams.userId not in userIds) {
  $state.go('root');
}
```

Comment: Alex - this looks like a solution, but what's correct code for "not in"? I've tried a loop but it exits and redirects me before it can go through the entire list of objects

Comment: can you show a sample of the (user) object? it probably comes from a http service?

Comment: Alex, I now found a solution for the "not in" which is a basic loop with a break if the id is found. Unfortunately as the page is loaded, it seems to skip the loop altogether and redirects before it has a chance to go through the loop.